# how void function can be return value? c++

Tags: c++, tcpclient

I do not understand, how void* function can be with return value. Code below, its work.

```
void *TcpClient::receive(int size=512)
{
char *buffer = new char[size];

if (recv(_sockfd , buffer , sizeof(buffer) , 0) < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "recv failed";
}

return buffer;
}
```

Comment: `void*` is not the same as `void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns `void*`, i.e. the pointer to memory, not `void`.